# How to create a tizen service application

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I need to WRITE senser data from samsung gearS2 to a .csv file continuously.currently i can do this but I need it to run this in the background which the gear user can't view or close. So I think I should use services but i can't understand the help given in tizen page. So can anyone give me a simple example code for a tizen service application.. It would be really help full. If you have any other methods which I can do this please mention them

Answer (score 1):

As you want to write a service for gear (wearable applications), you can write it using Tizen Web API features. Tizen Web API features support creating service and implementing selected features for wearable applications. Check the following URL:
https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/web-application/tizen-features/service-application#create

Answer (score 0):

The link below is a tutorial for Tizen service application. And you could find a template code from the Tizen SDK.

https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/native-application/application-framework/service-application

You may need to start your service application when the device boots up, however Tizen wearable (Gear S2) doesn't support that feature. Tizen service applications cannot be set to start when the device boots up. I think it might be for saving power consumption.

You can start your service application by adding an UI application that starts the service application. For doing that, the user of device needs to start your UI application. I think it is reasonable to protect user's private information from the malicious applications.